# Word 2010: How to Make Header Info Easily Changeable Across Section Breaks

Tags: microsoft-word, version-control

I have a 10-page document that describes a procedure on how to do something.  Each page has a Revision letter in a header, but all pages need to keep the same "Page-1" Revision.  Page-7 has a different format, such that it is defined as a different Section, but needs to keep the same Revision as Page-1.  If I change the Revision on Page-1, I always have to remember that Page-7 has that different format, so I need to also go to Page-7 and change that Revision to be the same as on Page-1.  Is there a way to link items between different Sections so that, if I change the Revision on Page-1, the Revision on Page-7 will change automatically to that same Page-1 Revision?

Comment: See [RevNum](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-RevNum-field-40eb1d97-4b55-4d5c-a5e5-88edf20612da?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) or [Build a custom Property](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-DocProperty-field-bf00526e-18cd-4515-8c8e-39d59094395a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)